# I'm using cd command but not working when going to folder

Tags: cmd, command-prompt

Problem with `cd` command.

I have tried `cd desktop` it took me to `c:\Users\pekka\Desktop>`

And on desktop I have a folder `Summersemester` so I wrote `cd Summersemester`, it gives error message

> 'The system cannot find the path specified'

from desktop to folder

Comment: i have used dir command but it shows my folder in not on desktop but it is...

Comment: screen shot? cd is pretty tried and true. If it says it’s not there then I bet either the folder or the cmd is not where you think it is.

Comment: There are generally [multiple](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/why-have-two-desktop-folders-for-each-users-both/627b8121-3d6b-484a-ac96-d514b5f123ae) [desktop](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start-winpc/why-does-my-win-10-have-three-desktop-folders/dcfc22f1-a255-48a6-b06c-de8c425fc3b4) folders.. are you sure you're in the right one?

Comment: Try an absolute path and with the `/D` option `CD /D "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Summersemester"`

Comment: im using windows 10 for first time, i think this OneDrive has replaced 'Desktop' ?

Answer (score 2):

i fixed problem like this:
I didnt know that in windows 10 desktop is replaced by 'OneDrive' so instead of writing 'cd desktop' i wrote 'cd OneDrive' then it found it.

Comment: For the majority of users this answer is **not** helpful. See my answer how to obtain the location of a special folder like `Desktop` if it was relocated.

Comment: No, OneDrive is Microsoft's optional service that offers cloud storage. It also creates a special folder called OneDrive and any files you place in there get copied to the cloud (i.e. backed up on Microsoft's servers so that you can access them from another machine through the internet). OneDrive has nothing to do with the Desktop. They're totally different concepts.

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two folders that make up the desktop that you see on your screen:

1. C:\Users\username\Desktop
2. C:\Users\Public\Desktop

The second one contains files and shortcuts that are visible on everyone's desktop. Perhaps the file you can see on your desktop is actually on the public desktop. In which case, you'll have to `cd` to \Users\Public\Desktop instead.

Answer (score 1):

It is by no way a standard setting that the `Desktop` is relocated to `OneDrive`

A lot of the `special folders` ***can*** [be relocated](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-move-default-user-folders-onedrive-windows-10) and also to `OneDrive`

In your question you don't explicitly tell from which location you entered the

```
cd desktop
```

Implicitly you should have been in `%USERPROFILE%` in your case `c:\Users\pekka`

And there might be a folder with the name `Desktop` but it is not true one, as this was relocated.

Usually this fixed location is presumed but the correct way is to lookup the actual special folder location with something like this in PowerShell:

```
[environment]::getfolderpath('Desktop')
```

Or wrapped in cmd/batch

```
powershell -nop -c "[environment]::getfolderpath('Desktop')"
```

or to get the location into a variable(cmd)

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %A in (`powershell -nop -c "[environment]::getfolderpath('Desktop')"`) do @set "Desktop=%A"
```

get the location into a variable(batch)

```
@Echo off
for /f "usebackq delims=" %A in (
    `powershell -nop -c "[environment]::getfolderpath('Desktop')"`
) do set "Desktop=%A"
```

---

To get a list of special folders and the current locations,
run this PowerShell script:

```
## Q:\Test\2018\06\08\Enum-SpecialFolders.ps1

$SpecialFolders = [Environment+SpecialFolder]::GetNames([Environment+SpecialFolder])
ForEach ($SpecialFolder in $SpecialFolders) {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        SpecialFolderName = $SpecialFolder
        SpecialFolderLocation = ([Environment]::GetFolderPath($SpecialFolder))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is new but I never explicitly told OneDrive to sync my Desktop (that I'm aware of) either and ran into the same issue.

To bring back the 'Desktop' folder under **C:\Users\User**, I tried clicking

```
One Drive -> Settings -> Account -> Choose Folders -> Desktop
```

And saw some bizarre message that said (I'm paraphrasing)

> Cannot stop syncing Desktop. This is an important folder in Windows.

which prevented the unchecking of the box. I deselected '*Files in Desktop*' beneath it and this allowed me to stop syncing Desktop. Just a warning, my Desktop does not have anything useful on it, but you may want to back up these files or move them first if this happens to you.

In Powershell, my actual Desktop folder returned under

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop
```

immediately afterwards and Onedrive now has a Desktop folder which is where the files moved to (again be careful, may help to back up your files first if you try this). There may be some separate setting which can revert this, resyncing the 'Desktop' folder in Onedrive now just syncs a folder called 'Desktop' in Onedrive, not the one you see on your Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I actually had challenges with cd from my desktop. This is how I went about it

1. cd onedrive
2. cd desktop
3. cd your folder